# Dashed line using writeablebitmap

Tags: c#, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

Are there a way when using writeablebitmap with writeablebitmapEx to draw a dashed line? Without having to manually calculate the dashes and create multiple lines to create the dashing effect?

Comment: Is this XAML? In that case you can do this just by defining a style on Separator element.

Comment: Short answer: No. There is no explicit support for dashed and/or dotted lines in *WriteableBitmapEx*. I have not tried it myself, but you might be able to experiment with `DrawLinePenned`, where you can provide an arbitrary `WriteableBitmap` object as your pen component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use DrawLinePenned with a BitmapContext pen. You can use another image as pen or just create it on the fly.